# Splitting data between azure sql and azure dwh

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

I am working on a on perm migration project which requires transactional database for 70% of its use case. These 70% of use cases will use 25% of data volume. Rest of the use cases and data volume will be used for reporting purposes.

My plan is to use perhaps 1TB of sqldb and for rest use dwh.

First question is that how can sync data between azure sqldb and azure dwh. And how frequent it could be ? What if I want near real-time data availability in dwh for reporting

Comment: CDC can be used to move data to Synapse SQL.  This can be done as frequently as you want.  There are a few other similar technologies depending on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

70% transactional use cases with 25% data volume means most of your data is used for reporting (75%). So, instead of creating two data stores (Azure SQL DB and Dedicated SQL Pool), you can store all of your data in Dedicated SQL Pool and you can use it for both, Transactional and real-time analysis.

> Using two data stores will definitely result in high latency and low
> performance.

With Dedicated SQL Pool, you can Optimize transactions in Azure Synapse Analytics and using Azure Stream Analysis you can analyze the data real time.

Refer the below official documents to know more about these services and how to deploy the same.

[Use Azure Stream Analytics with dedicated SQL pool in Azure Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-integrate-azure-stream-analytics)

[Optimize transactions with dedicated SQL pool in Azure Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-transaction-best-practices)

Comment: Thanks. One of the reason i was leaning towards 2 dbs is to reduce the cost of database. with 1 instance (assuming we will go for 4TB storage), it would cost around $4000ish. is there a way this cost be reduce? splitting data into smaller/cost affective instances?